# Handlebars helper does not show thousands separator

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm using Handlebars v3.0.3. I am attempting to get a value showing up with a thousands separator and 2 decimal points. In javascript this is simple enough, but for some reason when the template is rendered it is removing the comma's separator.

Here is the handlebars helper

```js
   Handlebars.registerHelper ("toFixed", function (aValue, aDigits) {

      if (!aDigits) {
         aDigits = 2;
      }

      if (!isNaN (aValue) && Number.isInteger (Number (aDigits))) {
         aValue = new Intl.NumberFormat ("en-US", { minimumFractionDigits : aDigits, maximumFractionDigits : aDigits }).format (aValue);
      }

      return aValue;

   });
```

Then the template is

```html
   <div>{{toFixed dailyAmount}}</div>
   <div>{{toFixed totalAmount}}</div>
```

If I run the function in the console it displays the amount as expected, for example "3012.2" will turn into "3,012.20". But when it renders in the template it displays "3012.20". I get the same result when I attempted to do `aValue = aValue.replace (/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');` or tried `return aValue.toString();`. Any suggestions?

Comment: the regex works, but not after a `.`: https://regex101.com/r/yG6mMt/1

Comment: maybe first convert the number to a string. numbers don't have the `replace` function

Comment: `return aValue.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');`

Comment: @Antoni Thanks, I did try this but no success. It returns correctly in a developer console but the comma's are refusing to show up in the rendering. I suspect something else is removing it. I just haven't been able to track down what it is.